# Stack allocation limit for programs on a Linux 32 bit machine

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

In C++ how much can the stack segment grow before the compiler gives up and says that it cannot allocate more memory for stack.

Using gcc on a linux (fedora) 32 bit machine.

Comment: Are you talking about how large the stack can grow at *runtime*, or how much space the compiler will allocate for a *single frame* at compile time? At runtime, the compiler isn't going to be the part that gives up.

Comment: Yeah how much can stack grow for a program at runtime, is there a limit to it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Under UNIX, if you are running bash run

```
$ ulimit -a
```

it will list various limits including stack size. Mine is 8192kb. You can use ulimit to change the limits.

Also, you can use ulimit() function to set various limits from within your program.

```
$ man 3 ulimit
```

Under Windows see [StackReserveSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712569(VS.71).aspx) and [StackCommitSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712568(VS.71).aspx)

In practice stack addresses begin at high addresses (on a 32-bit platform, close to the 3GB limit) and decrease while memory allocation begins at low addresses. This allows the stack and memory to grow until whole memory is exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

On my 32 bit linux, its 8192K bytes. So it *should* be the same on your machine.

```
$ uname -a
Linux TomsterInc 2.6.28-14-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 8 07:21:34 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
$ ulimit -s
8192
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows (and I think Linux) both operate on the *big stack model* assumption, that is, there is one stack (per thread) whose space is preallocated before the thread starts.
I suspect the OS simply assigns virtual memory space of the preallocated size to that stack area, and adds real memory pages underneath as the end of the stack is advanced beyond a page boundary until the upper limit ("ulimit") is reached.ck

Since OSes often place stacks well away from other structure, when ulimit is reached, it is just possible that the OS might be able to expand the stack, if when the overflow occurs nothing else has shown up next to the stack.   In general, if you are building a program complex enough enough to overflow the stack, you are likely allocating memory dynamically and there is no gaurantee that the area next to the stack didn't get allocated.  If such memory is allocated, of course the OS can't expand the stack where it is.

This means the application cannot count on the stack being expanded automatically by the OS. In effect, the stack *can't* grow.

In theory, an application exhausting its stack might be able to start a new thread with a larger stack, copy the existing stack and continue, but as practical matter I doubt this can be done, if for no other reason than pointers to local variables stack will need adjusting and C/C++ compilers don't make it possible to find such pointers and adjust them.
Consequence: ulimit has to be declared before the program starts, and once exceeded, the program dies.

If one wants a stack that can expand arbitrarily, it is better to switch to a language that uses heap-allocated activation records.  Then you simply don't run out until your address space is used up.   32 or 64 bit VM spaces ensure you can do a lot of recursion with this techniquie.

We have a parallel programming language called PARLANSE, that does heap allocation to enable thousands of parallel computational grains (in practice) to recurse arbitrarily this way.